# Determine the data structure

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, data-structures, mongoose-schema

I'm new in Mongo. Please help determine the data structure. I have branches, each branch has name and screens count, and each of them can have many playlists, each playlist has name, startDate, endDate, totalTime and Files. I need to say to each file on what screen it should be in what order and it's show time. And I want to use a file in different playlists with different properties

```
    const FileSchema = Schema({
    url: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    showTime: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    screen: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    order: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

const PlaylistSchema = Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    endDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    files: [FileSchema]
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

const BranchSchema = Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    screens: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    playlists: [Playlists]
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

Comment: See mongo takes in json structure, so you only need to figure out the model, which you already have, now create model classes in backend language of your choice, pick a ORM layer and then push the model to mongo server.

Comment: I understand it. I need to know is my data structure is right.

Comment: Can you describe what are the different data access patterns you have ? What are you concerns regarding the current model ?

Comment: I want to know is it ok or not.

Comment: Could you be so kind and give an example JSON of your data structure?

Comment: Here are some resources to help: 1. [Building With Patterns - A Summary](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-a-summary) (Mongo Blog): TLDR; - 12 schema design patterns with pros, cons, and use cases. 2. [Data Model Design](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/) (official docs). TLDR; - choose embedded docs or a normalized model. MongoDB 3. [Atlas Developer Support](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/support/) - If you're on Atlas, you get 30 days of free Developer support. The official support team can answer questions as you explore options for your schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling multi layer Many to Many relationships is always headache.
It's a good idea to design such stuff as Relational database does and use lookups to manage all things.

and it will make more sense if we remove an array of ids from the collection `playlists` and `files` and add reference to the child node.

In both the cases we have to lookup for the details. but advantag will be reading performance hence we are storing less data in single collection object. more data in root object will slow down query response.

```
const FileSchema = Schema({
    playlistId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    url: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    showTime: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    screen: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    order: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

const PlaylistSchema = Schema({
    branchId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    endDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

const BranchSchema = Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    screens: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

if you don't want to many collections and your `PlaylistSchema` does not contain too much properties you can make it Array of objects inside your `BranchSchema` and use its _id field to manage `FileSchema`.

```
const BranchSchema = Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    screens: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    branches: [
        {

            name: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            screens: {
                type: Number,
                required: true
            },
        }
    ]
});
```